# intelij datagrip doesn't open mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, intellij-idea, intellij-datagrip

Since the last update to datagrip 2019.1.3, datagrip doesn't open mongo collections anymore.

Double clicking any collection loads the collection's overview but not the data view.

[image]

[image]

The database is successfully connected, mongo shell and all else work, but the data isn't shown.

Here's an excerpt of datagrip's logs

```
2019-06-08 13:11:10,907 [ 680986]   INFO -     org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=MULTIPLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500} 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,907 [ 680986]   INFO -     org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,908 [ 680987]   INFO -     org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,911 [ 680990]   INFO -  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:33, serverValue:143}] to localhost:27017 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,911 [ 680990]   INFO -     org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 0, 6]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=523564} 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,912 [ 680991]   INFO -     org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Discovered cluster type of STANDALONE 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,914 [ 680993]   INFO -  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:34, serverValue:144}] to localhost:27017 
2019-06-08 13:11:10,917 [ 680996]   INFO -  org.mongodb.driver.connection - Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:34, serverValue:144}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
```

I encountered the same bug some months ago, that time simply rolling back the version helped, but now whatever I rollback datagrip to, the collection's data isn't shown any more. I've restarted my mac, invalidated caches and restart datagrip (multiple times). Nothing helped.

How to make my premium priced product work like a premium priced product?

Comment: Do you use [MongoDB](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7141-mongo-plugin) plugin? Looks like it is known plugin's issue: https://github.com/dboissier/mongo4idea/issues/270

Answer (score 1):

I would try the latest EAP from JetBrains. Since October 04 2019 they also support simple MongoDB interactions. 
You can find out more on the [2019.3 EAP page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2019/10/04/datagrip-2019-3-eap/).

Another alternative to viewing your MongoDB is [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/). This is also free in the non studio version.

**Edit:**
Now Jetbrains Datagrip natively supports MongoDB.